# How can I convert my CSV file to d3.js force directed graph

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, adjacency-matrix

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
;A;B;C;DA;0;0;1;2;B;0;3;0;0;C;0;0;0;1;D;1;0;2;0
```

and I want to make a force directed graph out of it.

Do I need to convert it into a json file first, or can I immediately use the CSV file? Also, the actual CSV file is much larger (1053x1053), with values from 0-9, so the links have to be weighted as well.

I have never worked with d3.js before so I am a bit lost. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

D3 has a property that allow you to deal with csv files. usually you write `d3.csv('path')` to access the data in the csv file so you don't really need to convert them into a json object. I attached below some references for converting csv in d3. [link to d3 wiki](https://d3-wiki.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/master/CSV/)